# SQLite multiply columns to update a third column

Tags: database, sqlite

I am trying to do what I think should be a simple SQLite operation. I want to multiply two columns from separate tables and put the results in a new column in the first table. The following runs, but produces a column of all 0.0:

```
UPDATE table 1
SET columnC = (SELECT (table1.columnB * table2.columnX)
               FROM table 1
               INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.columnA = table2.columnA);
```

If I isolate the SELECT statement in parentheses and run it on its own, I get the right values, but I don't know how to insert these into a column in the table.

```
SELECT (table1.columnB * table2.columnX)
       FROM table 1
       INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.columnA = table2.columnA;
```

Any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue might be that you aren't restricting the update so it is applying it to the every row for every row so at the end of it **columnC** would be the same value throughout.

e.g. Assuming :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (columnA INTEGER,columnX INTEGER);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1,5,0),(2,7,0),(3,8,0),(4,3,0);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(1,4),(2,3),(3,10),(4,21);

SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.columnA = table2.columnA;
```

The result (tables unchanged, so the base data, both tables joined highlighted is table 2 columns) :-
[image]

#### Example 1 - How you are doing it

Using (your way i.e. `WHERE`'s commented out) :-

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET columnC = 
    (SELECT (table1.columnB * table2.columnX)
           FROM table1
           INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.columnA = table2.columnA
           --WHERE table1.columnA = 3
    )
--WHERE columnA = 3
;

SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.columnA = table2.columnA
```

The result is (all ColumnC's changed to **20** i.e. 4 * 5 as per Table1.ColumnA * Table2.ColumnX for where ColumnA's are 1) :-

[image]

#### Example 2 - restricting to 1 row using `WHERE`

Adding the `WHERE`'s then the result is :-

[image]

#### Example 3 - Updating all rows

Now if you wanted to update all rows then you could use WITH ... UPDATE e.g.

```
WITH updates(ID, newvalue) AS (
    SELECT table1.columnA,
        table1.columnB * table2.columnX 
    FROM table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.columnA = table2.columnA
)
UPDATE TABLE1 SET columnC = 
    (
    SELECT newvalue
    FROM updates
    WHERE table1.columnA = ID
    )
;
```

Which would result in :-

[image]

Comment: This was exactly the explanation an SQLite noob like me needed. Many thanks, MikeT.